# Same code gives different answer, I dont understand why

Tags: int

I really have nothing to say, I dont understand why I dont get the same answers when i type hej and ymid out. When I print them out `hej` is 286 and `ymid` is 200. `y`= 200 so I guess in the `ymid` code the part after `y`+ becomes 0 for some reason, so `hej`=200+86 while `ymid=`200+0;

```
 public class Triangle extends Shape {
    int side;
    int x= super.x;
    int y=super.y;
    double ymid= y+Math.sqrt(side*side-(side/2)*(side/2)); 
    int hej;
 }

public Triangle(int xStart2, int yStart2, int sidlängd){
    super(xStart2, yStart2);
    side=sidlängd;
    hej=(int) (y-Math.sqrt(side*side-(side/2)*(side/2)));
}
```

Comment: You might specify the language here. Java I'm guessing?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have `ymid = y + ...` and `hej = (int) (y - ...`.  Note the plus/minus difference.